# Is there a common keyboard combination to move text?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, text-editing

I'd like to know if it is possible to move a selection of text using the keyboard on Windows 8 Pro.

In many pieces of software holding down either ctrl or alt and using the arrow keys will increase or decrease the size of text selection. Once the text is selected though, if I want to move it to another place in the document I have to go back to the mouse to drag it. I'd love to know if there is a keyboard combination I can use to move the text left/right/up/down etc once I have it selected in a document.

I realize this is most likely software dependent and may work differently depending how the specific software was written. The specific software I would like to use this in is Adobe Dreamweaver CC, but I would be interested to know about other software as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think think there are any generalized shortcuts, but in notepad++, Ctrl-Shift-Up/Down will move the line up and down . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can type Ctrl-X to cut the text, then use arrow keys to the place where you want the text to appear, and Ctrl-V to insert the cut text. This will work in just about all applications.

Comment: I should have mentioned I'd like to do it without cut/paste. I'd like to save whats in my clipboard.

Comment: I don't think there is a general shortcut that doesn't use cut/paste.

Comment: Well I guess this is as close as I'll get.